# DropdownFor and assigning Class on each <option>

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to get a dropdownfor to handle adding a class to each option where the class is the text of the option?  So by way of example:

```
<option class = "Example-1" value = "101" >Example 1<option>
<option class = "Example-2" value = "102" >Example 2<option>
<option class = "Example-3" value = "103" >Example 3<option>
```

Is this possible or am I going to need to look at a javascript/jquery solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that out of the box (you can only assign a class to the `<select>` parent)... you may need to [create your own HtmlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs). Or you could do it in javascript on page load and just loop through all the options

Comment: Since you're using MVC can't you use `foreach` on the select list, and then add option tag with whatever attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `DropDownListFor` helper doesn't allow it but what you can do is create the select element yourself.

```
<select name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.MyProperty)" id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.MyProperty)">
    @foreach (var example in examples) 
    {
        <option value="@example.Value" class="@example.CssClass" @(Model.MyProperty == example.Value ? "selected" : "")>@example.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Using `NameFor` and `IdFor` will make model binding work as it normally would.